# how to call controller action in ajax url

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to call the controller method in ajax url to dynamically populate the dropdown based on value from another dropdown. The value I am getting is string, when I call this method using ajax url it always refers to 'show' method. My ajax call

```
$('#users').change(function() {
  url: '/users/update_groups',
  data: {name: $(this).val()},
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

In my users_controller.rb

```
def update_groups user_name
  # returns list of groups
end
```

How to call this method using ajax url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#users").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "users/update_groups",
      type: "POST",
      data: {name: $(this).val()},
      success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
      }
  });
});
```

try the above code once it may work and let me know.....will try to help some other way if it don't work.....

Comment: thanks .for your reply. this code also doesn't call the update_groups method. In parameter id is passing and not name

Comment: it should work , will u give detailed description of your problem