# Ajax is not getting response from call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, response

I have tried many things but not getting response from this.
I am trying to retrieve token from mydomin/token and it is responding well. I debugged that and its working fine but Ajax is not taking the response.
I am using this

```
<script>
    //working but not getting response
    function myFunction1() {
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Account/CheckLogin?Email=" + $("#username").val()
            + "&password=" + $("#password").val(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).fail(showError);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my server code

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult CheckLogin(Account account)
        {
            Result obj = new Result();
            if (!account.Equals( null))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(account.Email);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(account.Password);
                var result = db.Users.Any(x => (x.Username.Equals(account.Email) || x.Email.Equals(account.Email)) && x.Password.Equals(account.Password));
                if (result)
                {
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    obj.txt = true;
                    return Json(obj,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            obj.txt = false;
            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

What i am getting response in browser and Post man is

```
{
txt: false
}
```

But ajax is not giving any response in data not showing alert. Even i did this to make sure but no alert not shown

```
 success: function (data) {
                alert("Hi");
            }
```

I followed this and some other links on stack but didn't worked for me.
[how to call controller action in ajax url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133549/how-to-call-controller-action-in-ajax-url)

Comment: add dataType: 'json' to your ajax call

Comment: How are you calling the `myFunction1` function ?

Answer (score 0):

if you can't see alert message then the ajax call wasn't success,
please try to debug it from the browser (chrome)
hit f12 and check if you have any error and select network tab and then scroll through requests made to the server and locate the one made by your ajax call click on it and then you will find what is the problem
[you should be able to find your ajax call here in red if it was failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMhnN.png)

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I have debugged my code its going fine in controller and controller is sending returning JSON. But it is not been received in Success method.

Comment: @Cyclonecode i agree BUT i can't comment i don't have 50 reputations

Comment: GET http://localhost:59335/Account/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
Login:17 GET http://localhost:59335/Account/assets/stylesheets/pixel-admin.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
Login:18 GET http://localhost:59335/Account/assets/stylesheets/widgets.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
Login:19 GET http://localhost:59335/Account/assets/stylesheets/rtl.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: This is what it is saying in browser @AhmadAlbaz

Comment: @Inshalirshad yes please check the image attached, you have to debug it from the browser, one case i had where the data size were too much to be serialized as json and i had the same problem as yours everything goes fine in the controller and no exception occurred untill i debugged it from there

Comment: @Inshalirshad add this to your `.fail()` function `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});`

Comment: this is what it is saying i browser [link](https://ibb.co/iTOA5R) its giving error in css but it is not the matter as i looked into it because css is fine

Comment: add the code I showed above, and it will show you the error.

Comment: @julekgwa  this is what it is showing 'Request failed: error'

Comment: The problem is with your url or your back end, go do some debugging.

Comment: check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was trying to fire Ajax off the click event of a submit button that had a server side click event setup. I had to make the button just a simple button (i.e.  )